# call FB.login() after FB.init() automatically

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

i`m developing an app for Facebook.

My Code:

```
function init() {
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        var appID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

        FB.init({ appId: appID, 
              status: true, 
                  cookie: true, 
                  xfbml: true});



        login();
    };

    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement("script"); 
        e.async = true;
        e.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js?xfbml=1";
        document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
    }());
};
function login() {

    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            if (response.perms) {
                // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
                // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
            } else {
                // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
            }
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
        }
    }, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
};
```

I want to call the "init" function and after "init" should call the "login" function (open up the Facebook Login Window) automatically.

But i always get "b is null"
 `FB.provide('',{ui:function(f,b){if(!f....onent(FB.UIServer._resultToken));}});` Error in Firebug.

Can anybody help me?
Does anybody have the same problem?

Thanks

Comment: I hava an Button "Start Facebook" on my HTML Page.This Button call the "init" Function. When I use 2 Buttons (one call init the other call login) everything works great, but i only want ONE Button.

Answer (score 1):

You needn't have the facebook init stuff in a function, it can go straight on the page, then it will load at the same time, rather than waiting for a button click to load. Then you just need the login logic on the logiin button

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        var appID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        FB.init({
              appId: appID, 
              status: true, 
              cookie: true, 
              xfbml: true
        });

        // This bit adds the login functionality to the login
        // button when api load is complete
        document.getElementById("login").onclick = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.session) {
                if (response.perms) {
                    // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
                    // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
                } else {
                    // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
                }
            } else {
                // user is not logged in
            }
        }, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
    }
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement("script"); 
        e.async = true;
        e.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js?xfbml=1";
        document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
<a id="login" href="somewhere.html">My login button</a>
</body>
</html>
```

You can put the login stuff in a method and automatically call the it after the FB.init, but most browsers will block the pop up window. You are better off waiting for the user to click a login button to make sure they see it properly, and it is generally good practise to only make things happen when the user explicitly requests them to. I think the facebook 'good practice' guide also mentions this somewhere.

Comment: Thx, but i have to put the "init" in a function. Isn`t it possible to load login automatically after init?

Comment: well yes, but  all your users' browsers will block the pop up, and its generally a bad idea to force pop ups on people

Comment: I will not force pop ups :) I want one button. If user click this button => init Facebook Connection and open the login Window.

Comment: ah, I see. Why don't you want to init beforehand? Loading the api when the user clicks the button could take time and delay the response which could be annoying for users. I tried that code and it seems to work ok for me. Do you have a live example?

Comment: I load the Code from an xml File and integrate the functionality during runtime. Do you have any idea, how to load FB.login automatically after FB.init?